# print values in c:forEach loop

Tags: java, database, jsp, arraylist

I can't set my ArrayList from database in response from Servlet to iterate on JSP page.

**Servlet:**

```
        ...
  //! Set Text
  request.setAttribute("texto", texto);
  request.setAttribute("textoInvertido", textoInvertido);

    try {
        //! Recovers Text List
        this.listaTextos = appController.todosOsTextos();
        ...
        }
        ...
        ArrayList<Text> list = (ArrayList<Text>) this.listaTextos;

  //! Set It (?)
  request.setAttribute("list", list);

        ...
```

**Page:**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Your Words:</label>
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
       ${item.getTexto}<br>
    </c:forEach>
<div>
```

**Debug:**
[image: Debug]

Why `list`, still out of response and `Texto`/`TextoInvertido` no?

Comment: not sure if Texto/TextoInvertido are included in response, but the list is there, why don't go to the page, i need to do this in doGet method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after break the head and searching thousands of answers:

this line is missing in head:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

IDE do not include automatically.

And in the `<li>` you call the attribute: `<li>item.Text</li>`not `getText`

Answer (score 0):

List will contain and print the necessary values only if its not null/empty. Based on the code snippet you posted, it seems like you're setting those values individually in the request scope rather than the Text object. Since you are invoking the values with ${item.getTexto} in your jsp, the values need to be set with Text.setTexto() rather than request.setAttribute("texto", texto);

Comment: `request.setAttribute("texto", texto);` this get the input of user, and goes to controller, the controller saves in DB, and inside the try, i go at the controller again, to `Select *` Object Textos, and save them in a arrayList, i get back an ArrayList<Textos> filled, as appears on debug, after this i set the list attribute like the `texto` (which works), but i can't only iterate on the list, to show dynamically